# How to set email alert for disk space usage for ubuntu instance on AWS?

Tags: monitoring, amazon-ec2, aws, cloud, amazon

I have an ubuntu instance on AWS and I want an email when 80% of disk space is consumed. I have checked the cloud watch but there is no such option to monitor disk space. There is only one option which is custom metric https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html but I am not sure that it will give an email alert. Please guide me for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

**1. Create an instance and attach the IAM Role :**

```
 AmazonEC2RoleforSSM
 CloudWatchAgentAdminPolicy
 CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy
 AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore
```

**2. [Install CloudWatch agent :](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-EC2-Instance-fleet.html) :** In the RunCommand , choose **AWS-ConfigureAWSPackage** to the install it on the desired Target.

**3. [Running the CloudWatch agent wizard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file-wizard.html) :** Start the CloudWatch agent configuration wizard by entering the following:

```
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard
```

At one stage, you will prompted by the wizard to choose which default predefined metrics you want and if you want to store the config in the SSM parameter store. I had chosen **Advanced** to include all metrics and **Yes**  to store in the config. 
Once completed , the entire config is available in the Parameter store in AWS Systems Manager. My config snippet has :

```
"disk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "used_percent",
                    "inodes_free"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
```

**4. Start the CloudWatch agent** 
There are 2 ways to start the agent :
a. From Run Command 
b. From command line with Systems Manager Parameter store.

The Run Command failed for some reason but the command line worked

```
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c ssm:configuration-parameter-store-name -s
```

c. If you encounter any error *No package collectd available* , install the necessary package to restart the agent.

**For Amazon Linux :**

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
sudo yum install collectd
```

**For Ubuntu :**

```
sudo apt-get install collectd collectd-utils
```

**5. CloudWatch console**

Create a Dashboard to monitor the instance metrics which is now available as custom namespaces via the CWAgent. You can also set necessary  Alarm to notify / email recipients.

---

**CloudWatch custom metrics**

[image]

---

**Previous post**

You may want to deploy Systems Manager (SSM) Agent installed on you instance to monitor and alert you for disk space usage. For this use, you will need to create a Role in IAM for the EC2 instance to send data to CloudWatch. Once that's complete, you can use a JSON script to monitor disk space from within the Run command of SSM.

More details are available at https://blog.justinworrell.com/2017/09/30/monitoring-free-disk-space-on-a-windows-ec2-instance-with-cloudwatch/

Comment: this is for windows instance but I am using ubuntu instance for that it is not working

Comment: Ubuntu Server AMIs starting with 16.04 has SSM installed readily with snap packages. You will want to see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-manual-agent-install.html#agent-install-ubuntu for the complete details

Comment: I have Ubuntu Server 18.04  and SSM is intalled by default. The only problem I am facing in the doc  https://blog.justinworrell.com/2017/09/30/monitoring-free-disk-space-on-a-windows-ec2-instance-with-cloudwatch/ is when I try to run a command, AWS-ConfigureCloudWatch is only available for windows platform. So I am not able to select my instance there.